# Long running task in MVC Controller and Session Timeout c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my controller that has a loop that can take hours to complete (downloading 100K records from the DB and searching everyone of these records in the DB for more data).

My question is, if the session timed out say after (20 minutes), will the action in my controller stop executing and my loop will be exited?

Thanks

Comment: Just a comment about design: consider moving long-running jobs to background worker? Controller is not good place to execute long running tasks..

Comment: Don't do it in your controller. Move it some where like a console application

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you guys!